# Storing binary trees in a vector - copy constr issue?

Tags: c++, tree

I have been having node = 0xdddddddd issues with my code. I believe I have narrowed it down to a Rule of Three issue and not having a copy constructor. I did try creating a copy constructor but I am unsure if I am implementing it correctly. Essentially, I am creating nodes, storing them in a binary tree object, which I am storing in a vector. Do I need to create a copy constructor all the way down?

Environment.cpp

```
void Environment::evolve() {
    std::cout << "> evolving function" << std::endl;
    std::vector<Tree> popvec;

    // Generate initial pop trees and store in vector
    std::cout << "> generating initial population" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <= Popsize-1; i++) {
        Tree membertree(Maxdepth);
        //popvec.push_back(membertree);
        popvec.emplace_back(membertree);
    } // <- A deconstructor is being called here that is causing the error
      // If I understand right it is destructing the copy from putting it
      // into the vector
```

Tree.cpp

```
// Constructor
Tree::Tree() {
    root = NULL;
    fitness = rand();
    depth = 0;

}

// Overload constructor
Tree::Tree(int maxdepth) {
    root = NULL;
    fitness = rand();
    depth = 0;
    while (TreeDepth(root) < maxdepth) {
        addNode(root);
    }

}

// Copy constructor
Tree::Tree(const Tree &obj, int maxdepth) {
    root = NULL;
    fitness = obj.fitness;
    depth = 0;
    while (TreeDepth(root) < maxdepth) {
        addNode(root);
    }
}

// Destructor
Tree::~Tree() {
    freeNode(root);
    root = NULL;
}

// Post traversal node deletion
void Tree::freeNode(Node* node) {
    if (node != NULL) {
        freeNode(node->left); // This is where the error pops up
        freeNode(node->right);
        delete node;
    }
}

// Adds a node to the tree
void Tree::addNode(Node* node) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        Node* temp = new Node();
        root = temp;
    }
    else if (node->left == NULL) {
        Node* temp = new Node();
        node->left = temp;
    }
    else if (node->right == NULL) {
        Node* temp = new Node();
        node->right = temp;
    }
    else if (node->left != NULL) {
        addNode(node->left);
    }
    else if (node->right != NULL) {
        addNode(node->right);
    }
}
```

Edit: someone asked for tree depth

```
int Tree::TreeDepth(Node* node) {
    if (node == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    int nLeft = TreeDepth(node->left);
    int nRight = TreeDepth(node->right);
    return (nLeft > nRight) ? (nLeft + 1) : (nRight + 1);
}
```

Node.cpp

```
Node::Node() {
    functiontype = 0;
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
    up = NULL;
}

// Do I need a copy constructor here as well?

Node::~Node() {

}
```

Edit: I seem to have gotten further with this but now it seems to have an error further down when it tries to randomize the vector

```
// Copy constructor
Tree::Tree(const Tree& obj) {
    fitness = obj.fitness;
    depth = obj.depth;
    if(obj.root == NULL){
        root = NULL;
    }
    else {
        copyTree(this->root, obj.root);
    }
}

void Tree::copyTree(Node * thisRoot, Node * sourceRoot) {
    if (sourceRoot == NULL)
    {
        thisRoot = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        thisRoot = new Node;
        thisRoot->left = sourceRoot->left;
        thisRoot->right = sourceRoot->right;
        copyTree(thisRoot->left, sourceRoot->left);
        copyTree(thisRoot->right, sourceRoot->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where in that copy constructor you actually copy the other `Tree`'s `Node`s. It looks to me like you're just continually adding your root node instead of the nodes from the other tree.

Comment: Yes that is a good point and I am not really sure how to go about copying a binary tree like that. I could perhaps traversal through the one being copied. Hmm.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Something like for each `Node` in `obj`: Create new `Node`, set the `newNode->functiontype = objNode->functiontype`, and then `addNode(newNode)`.

Comment: Rikocar is dead right about the copy constructor function signature. It should get max depth from the tree being copied. You shouldn't need to supply it as a parameter.

Comment: Ive edited it some. I seemed to have missed initializing a pointer now that I will have to search for. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use:

```
popvec.emplace_back(Maxdepth);
```

Instead of:

```
popvec.emplace_back(membertree);
```

Then, the copy constructor should not be called. Try doing this.

**Edit:**

I do not have much time, sorry.

The correct function signature for the copy constructor would be:

```
Tree::Tree(const Tree &obj)
```

As it is, what you marked as the copy constructor probably isn't even called.

Could you provide the code for what `TreeDepth` does?

Let me know if there are any other problems.

**Edit:**

The function I gave earlier didn't work, I didn't check thoroughly enough, sorry.

I have tested your program and I am able to fill a vector of `Tree`s. What I did was change `copyTree` to:

```
void Tree::copyTree(Node *& thisRoot, Node * sourceRoot)
{
    if (sourceRoot == nullptr)
    {
        thisRoot = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        thisRoot = new Node;
        thisRoot->left = sourceRoot->left;
        thisRoot->right = sourceRoot->right;
        copyTree(thisRoot->left, sourceRoot->left);
        copyTree(thisRoot->right, sourceRoot->right);
    }
}
```

All I did was change the `thisRoot` parameter to be a `Node*&`. Previously, changing `thisRoot` did not change `root`, it only made the pointer local to the function point to the newly created node.

I do not know if `fitness` or `depth` do anything but currently they seem pretty useless.

Comment: I appear to be getting the same issue when I do that.

Comment: Hi, I have managed to store the binary trees in the vector. Thank you for your help. Do you know why it would give the error again after if I try to std:random_shuffle(popvec.begin(), popvec.end()); for it?

Comment: I figured out where my problem was, sorry for bothering you. My destructor was not working correctly. It has been slow going on this program but progress is being made.